# How to parameterize .json file in rest assured?

Tags: json, rest-assured, web-api-testing

I am new to rest assured automation framework, so need help. I have to automate a simple API wherein I send the request in body.

```
given().log().all().contentType("application/json").body(payload).when().log().all().post("THE 
   POST URL").then().log().all().assertThat().statusCode(200);
```

I have to read the request from json file, and I am able to read the request from the .json file successfully. But I want to parameterize the values, and unable to understand on how to parameterize the file. Following is the sample .json file:

```
{
"id" : 5,
"name" : "Harry"
}
```

I do not want to hardcode the values of id and name here, but instead parameterize them using data  providers or any other method. Any pointers on the same would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

A good practice for API testing using Rest-Assured is POJO approach. It helps you avoid manipulating json file (one kind of hardcode)

Step 1: You define a POJO

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Person {
    private int id;
    private String name;
}
```

I use lombok for generating verbose code.

Step 2: Create Data-provider method

```
@DataProvider(name = "create")
public Iterator<Person> createData() {
    Person p1 = new Person(1, "Json");
    Person p2 = new Person(2, "James");
    Person p3 = new Person(3, "Harry");
    return Arrays.asList(p1,p2,p3).iterator();
}
```

Step 3: Write test

```
@Test(dataProvider = "create" )
void test1(Person person) {
    given().log().all().contentType(JSON)
            .body(person)
            .post("YOUR_URL")
            .then().log().all().assertThat().statusCode(200);
}
```

You need to add 2 lib into your project classpath to make above code work.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.20</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Good solution. What if the json structure is not constant but dynamic?

Comment: @MansoorShaikh If "dynamic" means new json for different API, then create new POJO for mapping. If "dynamic" means just add/remove some fields in json for same API, then levarage annotations in jackson lib to do that.